# Java 8 function that takes a List<V> and return a HashMap<K, List<V>>

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-stream

I am trying to create a function in Java 8 that takes a list as a parameter and returns a `HashMap` as a result.

I already did it in Java 7 but I want to do it by using Java 8 streams:

Here is the code in Java 7:

```
public static HashMap<String, List<Eleve>> getMentions(List<Eleve> liste){

    HashMap<String, List<Eleve>> listeMentions = new HashMap<String, List<Eleve>>();

    List<Eleve> noMention = new ArrayList<Eleve>();
    List<Eleve> mentionAB = new ArrayList<Eleve>();
    List<Eleve> mentionB  = new ArrayList<Eleve>();
    List<Eleve> mentionTB = new ArrayList<Eleve>();


    for (Eleve eleve: liste) {
        if (eleve.getAverage()>=12 && eleve.getAverage()<14) {mentionAB.add(eleve);}
        else if(eleve.getAverage()>=14 && eleve.getAverage()<16) {mentionB.add(eleve);}
        else if (eleve.getAverage()>=16) {mentionTB.add(eleve);}
        else{noMention.add(eleve);}
    }

    listeMentions.put("No mention", noMention);
    listeMentions.put("Mention AB", mentionAB); 
    listeMentions.put("Mention B",  mentionB);
    listeMentions.put("Mention TB", mentionTB);

    return listeMentions;
}
```

I tried with the `collect(Collectors.toMap)` stream but I did not get the estimated outcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a method that accepts an `int` average and returns the corresponding group for that average.

```
public static String getGroup (int average) {
    if (average >= 12 && average < 14) {
        return "Mention AB";
    } else if(average >= 14 && average < 16) {
        return "Mention B";
    } else if (average >= 16) {
        return "Mention TB";
    } else {
        return "No mention";
    }
}
```

Now you can use `Collectors.groupingBy` to group your instances by this criteria:

```
Map<String, List<Eleve>> listeMentions =
    liste.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> getGroup(e.getAverage())));
```

Alternately, you can pass the `Eleve` instance to the `getGroup()` method, so the stream pipeline will become:

```
Map<String, List<Eleve>> listeMentions =
    liste.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> getGroup(e)));
```

or, if you make `getGroup()` an instance method of `Eleve` (i.e `public String getGroup() {...}`):

```
Map<String, List<Eleve>> listeMentions =
    liste.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Eleve::getGroup));
```

Comment: You could also shorten the second snippet to: from `e -> getGroup(e)` to `SomeClass::getGroup`

Comment: @Lino Yep, I didn't do that because I didn't decide which class would contain that method :)

Comment: That's why I came up with a dummyname. Just wanted to mention that it's possible too. But not for you of course, you know that it's possible ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the help.

The groupingBy method was indeed the solution.

Instead of creating a function I created an ENUM and then use it into my steam, but It works the same way.
Here is the code:

```
public enum Mention
{
  BIEN, ASSEZ_BIEN,TRES_BIEN, BOF;

  public static Mention find(double average) {  
     if (average >= 12 && average < 14) {
            return ASSEZ_BIEN;
        } else if(average >= 14 && average < 16) {
            return BIEN;
        } else if (average >= 16) {
            return TRES_BIEN;
        } else {
            return BOF;
        }
}
```

}

```
public static Map<Object, List<Eleve>> getMentions8(List<Eleve> liste){
            Map<Object, List<Eleve>> listeMentions =
                    liste.stream()
                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> Mention.find(e.average)));
            return listeMentions;
        }
```

Comment: Why a `Map<Object, List<Eleve>>`? It should be a `Map<Mention, List<Eleve>>` instead. Ideally, an `EnumMap`, for which you should use the overloaded version of `Collectors.groupingBy` that accepts a map supplier.

Comment: If you are satisfied with Eran's answer then please accept it to give him credit for it.